# Aggregate columns based on different conditions?

Tags: sql, group-by, teradata, aggregate-functions, query-performance

I have a Teradata query that generates:

```
customer | order | amount | days_ago
123      | 1     | 50     | 2
123      | 1     | 50     | 7
123      | 2     | 10     | 19
123      | 3     | 100    | 35
234      | 4     | 20     | 20
234      | 5     | 10     | 10
```

With performance in mind, what’s the most efficient way to produce an output per customer where `orders` is the number of distinct orders a customer had within the last 30 days and `total` is the sum of the amount of the distinct orders regardless of how many days ago the order was placed?

Desired output:

```
customer | orders | total
123      | 2      | 160
234      | 2      | 30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your rules, maybe it takes two steps - de-duplicate first then aggregate:

```
SELECT customer, 
SUM(CASE WHEN days_ago <=30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS orders,
SUM(amount) AS total
 FROM
(SELECT customer, order, MAX-or-MIN(amount) AS amount, MIN-or-MAX(days_ago) AS days_ago
FROM your_relation
GROUP BY 1, 2) AS DistinctCustOrder
GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: I’m worried about performance suffering due to multiple selects, but it might be the only way.